# Give scheduling rights with security.conf

Tags: 16.04, security, configuration, users, schedule

I am running a C++ program which wants to enforce its own scheduling policy. It keeps giving warnings that it doesn't have the rights to, and I want to give it all the rights that it wants!

I tried doing:

```
sudo nano /etc/security/limits.conf
```

and adding:

```
@users          -       rtprio          99
@users          -       nice            -19
```

Then I did: `sudo usermod -aG users gsamaras`, where `gsamaras` is me, the one and only user.

After closing the terminal, and trying again, it still gives the warnings.

I also tried using `gsamaras` instead of `@users` in `limits.conf` directly, but still no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing user groups, or editing `/etc/security/limits.conf`, you need to logout and login again to make it work.

They are not going to be effective right away in your current session.